# Trying to create a view to set booleanfield to true but not updating

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

All of the users have a booleanfield first_visit that is set to true.

I created an alert with some information on the homepage and with a button at the end, when they click it, it will set the booleanfield to false and they will no longer see the "alert", its like a guide...

I extended the user model from django so this is what I did :

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_visit = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**My views.py**

```
def verification(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.first_visit = False
    user.save()
```

**My path**

```
path('first_visit/<user_id>', views.verification, name="firstvisit"),
```

**And the link in my template**

```
{% url 'firstvisit' user.id %}
```

But when i tried, it does not affect the model and it still set to true

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to edit `firs_visit` field in built-in `User` model, but its defined in extended `Profile` model, I think your answer is:

**My views.py**

```
def verification(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.profile.first_visit = False
    user.profile.save()
```

---

Also, if you implemented authenticated system like in Django documentation, and edit your `Profile` model a little bit, you could do it more easily:

**My views.py**

```
def verification(request, user_id):
    request.user.profile.first_visit = False
    request.user.profile.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    first_visit = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will stick with my model for now As we are two person working on the project.

I have tried your first view, however, it says that 'name 'user' is not defined'
Now I believe should already be in the profile ? 

Thanks again

Comment: My bad, i forgot to call the user in my view